# Node.getTextContent() is there a way to get text content of the current node, not the descendant's text

Tags: java, xml, dom

Node.getTextContent() returns the text content of the current node and its descendants.

is there a way to get text content of the current node, not the descendant's text.

Example

```
<paragraph>
    <link>XML</link>
    is a 
    <strong>browser based XML editor</strong>
    editor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor.
</paragraph>
```

expected output

```
paragraph = is a editor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor.
link = XML
strong = browser based XML editor
```

i tried below code

```
String str =            "<paragraph>"+
                            "<link>XML</link>"+
                            " is a "+ 
                            "<strong>browser based XML editor</strong>"+
                            "editor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor."+
                        "</paragraph>";

        org.w3c.dom.Document domDoc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;

        try {
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
            domDoc = docBuilder.parse(bis);         
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {         
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) domDoc;
        NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(
                domDoc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);

        for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {           
            String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
            System.out.println(tagname + "=" + ((Element)n).getTextContent());
        }
```

but it gives the output like this

```
paragraph=XML is a browser based XML editoreditor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor.
link=XML
strong=browser based XML editor
```

note the **paragraph** element contains the text of **link** and **strong** tag, which i dont want.
please suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is to filter children of your node `<paragraph>` to only keep ones with node type `Node.TEXT_NODE`.

This is an example of method that will return you the desired content

```
public static String getFirstLevelTextContent(Node node) {
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    StringBuilder textContent = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node child = list.item(i);
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            textContent.append(child.getTextContent());
    }
    return textContent.toString();
}
```

Within your example it means:

```
String str = "<paragraph>" + //
        "<link>XML</link>" + //
        " is a " + //
        "<strong>browser based XML editor</strong>" + //
        "editor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor." + //
        "</paragraph>";
Document domDoc = null;
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    domDoc = docBuilder.parse(bis);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) domDoc;
NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(domDoc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
    String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
    System.out.println(tagname + "=" + getFirstLevelTextContent(n));
}
```

Output:

```
paragraph= is a editor allows users to edit XML data in an intuitive word processor.
link=XML
strong=browser based XML editor
```

What it does is iterating on all the children of a Node, keeping only TEXT (thus excluding comments, node and so on) and accumulating their respective text content.

There is no direct method in `Node` or `Element` to get only the text content at first level.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the last for loop into the following one it behaves as you wanted

```
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {           
    String tagname = ((Element) n).getTagName();
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    NodeList children = n.getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0; i<children.getLength(); i++) {
        Node child = children.item(i);
        if(child.getNodeName().equals("#text"))
            content.append(child.getTextContent());
    }
    System.out.println(tagname + "=" + content);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this with Java 8 streams and a helper class:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class NodeLists
{
    /** converts a NodeList to java.util.List of Node */
    static List<Node> list(NodeList nodeList)
    {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++) {list.add(nodeList.item(i));}
        return list;
    }
}
```

And then

```
 NodeLists.list(node)
.stream()
.filter(node->node.getNodeType()==Node.TEXT_NODE)
 .map(Node::getTextContent)
 .reduce("",(s,t)->s+t);
```

Comment: With your code "as is" - get a compiler error of `The method filter((<no type> node) -> {}) is undefined for the type List<Node>`

Comment: This is 3 years later but I think I just forgot `.stream()` before `. filter(...`.

Comment: Dang you're good!  That fixed it, thanks I'm a newb when it comes to Java 8 and stream functionality. Thanks again for the help and quick response - I'm hoping your answer helps me as I'm having the same issue as the original OP!  Have a great evening and good luck on your PHD!

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly don't have any function for the actual node text but with a simple trick you can do it. Ask if the node.getTextContent() contains "\n", if that is the case then the actual node don't have any text.

Hope this help.