# How to extract XML nodes ignoring the descendent elements in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have structure in XML like this:

```
<allcontents>
    <notinteresting1>
       nothing relevant
    </notinteresting1>
    <notinteresting2>
       nothing relevant either
    </notinteresing2>
    i want just this content
</allcontents>
```

I would like to read the contents that are inside "allcontents" but outside any other element.

I tried to read the node with a code like this in Java

```
String allcontents =  eElement.getElementsByTagName(allcontents).item(0).getTextContent();
```

But this will return all the contents of the node, which is not what I am interested in.

Comment: Your question already exists in SO and there is a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191414/node-gettextcontent-is-there-a-way-to-get-text-content-of-the-current-node-no)

Comment: Thank you @jesusperaltac